# How see if Python interpreter using virtual environment?

Tags: debian, virtualenv, python-3.4

Please confirm or refute:
I have created python [3] virtual environment and installed some packages [for elpy]

```
$ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.4 pyvenv3/
$ source pyvenv3/bin/activate
$ easy_install rope
$ easy_install autopep8
$ easy_install yapf
$ easy_install jedi
$ easy_install flake8
$ easy_install importmagic [?]
```

The terminal prompt has changes to :

```
(pyvenv3)visteon@debian:~/Documents/bitbucket-python-scripts$
```

Does this mean that if I run Pyton3 from within this terminal window it will be running in the virtual environment pyvenv3 ? Is there a way to see (or confirm) that the started Python interpreter is using the virtual environment?

Using: Debian Jessie, Python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your normal prompt should be something like: `user@machine:`, but after you enter in the virtual environment, it changes to `(env_name) user@machine`.

If you still thinks your prompt is lying to you, you can do `pip freeze` and it will show you the packages installed through pip. Normally, if your virtualenv is new, you won't have any package.

Other way: if you have in your machine the command `python` as alias for python2.7 or a different python version of your virtualenv, just type `python` in the virtualenv and see the version.

EDIT: I forgot to answer your 2nd question. Yes, if you are inside a virtualenv, your `python` command would use you virtualenv python version (and packages installed in the virtualenv)